# How to determine why an agent pool is offline in Azure dev-ops

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I noticed that all of my builds suddenly got stuck. If I click the build I get the following error: All eligible agents are disabled or offline

When I check my agent pools I get the following:
[image]

How can I bring them online/determine why they are offline?

Comment: Well, you can start by going to the machine where the agent is and looking there. If the agent is offline, it can't report an error message about **why** it's offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The VM that host the build agents can have a auto shut down time. Make sure your build vm is running by going to Virtual machines in the azure portal

Comment: I had a similar problem but the VM was still alive.  I realized I was not installing the latest version of the agent tools.  Once I installed the latest tools the issue seems to be fixed (or at least it has not come back in the past few hours)

Comment: This didn't work for me. I reinstalled the deployment agent and it failed right off the bat. Restarting the VM fixes it short-term, but that's a workaround and not a solution.

Comment: I just started the service after installing the agent, and it works fine!

Answer (score 10):

Try logging into the VM, and run the run.cmd from an elevated powershell prompt in your agent directory. 
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops

Comment: Only for interactive mode agents, not for service mode.

Comment: @Ryebread You can manually stop the services and then run them with `run.cmd` to debug. I have just done the same and discovered the issue "The local machine's clock may be out of sync with the server time by more than five minutes. Please sync your clock with your domain or internet time and try again."

After you fix the issues, stop the console and start the services again.

Answer (score 7):

Login to powershell.Navigate to the agent folder where it contains run cmd prompt and config cmd prompt.

Execute the following command

.\run.cmd

Comment: I noticed that my agent folder is gone. How can that be?

Answer (score 3):

- Check the date and time on your VM. If it's wrong, correct it.
- Then run powershell as administrator and cd into the azagent folder that contains the run.cmd file (most likely C:\azagent\A4).
- Execute the following command:

  .\run.cmd

Answer (score 1):

For me, issue was suddenly agents were reporting offline on the portal.

1. Restarted the agent service in the VM - didn't help
2. Removed config file also didn't help because logs were showing that dev.azure.com wasn't connecting
3. Simply just restarting VM helped, but still couldn't able to find the cause.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I went as far as reinstalling the deployment agent (as a service) and it's still failing.

Answer (score 0):

My agent stopped going live when I updated our Azure Devops to the latest version 2019.1.3 iirc.

To solve this I did the following:

1. Went to services.msc on the agent machine. Stopped the existing service.
2. Went to agent folder and removed the existing configuration via "config.cmd remove"
3. Downloaded latest agent code from the Azure Devops Agent Pools portal page.
4. Replaced contents of old agent with new agent files.
5. Went back to agent folder and configured a new agent via "config.cmd". Told it to start as a service.

Voila! Service back running again.

Answer (score 0):

One of my Azure agents started showing as offline. As a test, I ran curl [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D) and got back an error "curl: (35) schannel: failed to receive handshake, SSL/TLS connection failed".

I fixed the issue by downloading IISCryptoCli.exe from https://www.nartac.com/Products/IISCrypto/Download and then running "IISCryptoCli.exe /template default /reboot".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by connecting to the agent via Remote Desktop Connection and running the "Run Puppet Agent" application.

Comment: Puppet agent doesn't seem to have anything to do with Azure DevOps pipelines.  How is this solution related to solving the problem?

Comment: @dcp In my case, the puppet agent manages configuration of the nodes pertaining to the agent pool. My answer presumes Puppet service is being utilized, although OP did not specify this. Let me know if you think this answer is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the agent from agent tab under releases.
There should be a server listed for the agent under agent tab.
Now connect to that server and check weather the agent batch file or cmd window is open or not.(this agent for is the same file which is downloaded while configuring the agent.if you are struggling to find the file then follow new agent steps and download zip again and search with that file name.)
Now open the(filename -run) file on that server with admin right if it is already not running. This will make agent online in devops portal.

Now check the agent tab again in devops portal under releases.

This

Comment: What does the "This" at the end mean? Is there supposed to be something following that?