# Console app download website gets 401 Unauthorized

Tags: c#, azure-devops

Given:
Visual Studio 2019
Windows 10 Pro
Windows 2016 Azure on premise
Company VPN

I'm working inside my company's VPN and I can access my Azure DevOps website to see my repo and builds in my web browser.

I'm trying to create a console app (for automating a process) that downloads a page from website, extract some status information, and email interested parties. I'll then schedule this task on task scheduler to check often.

> The status I'm trying to get in Azure DevOps is to check if a build
> agent is running.

However, I'm getting a 401 Unauthorized when trying to use WebClient on target url. What exactly is going on and what do I need to do to gain access?

```
private static WebsiteDataModel DownloadWebsite(string websiteURL)
{
    WebsiteDataModel output = new WebsiteDataModel();
    WebClient client = new WebClient();

    output.WebsiteUrl = websiteURL;
    output.WebsiteData = client.DownloadString(websiteURL);

    return output;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Try going to the DevOps page in an incognito window: you may find you need to log in. If not, you may have a corporate proxy for your browser that bypasses authentication. You might need to specify the proxy in your web client in C#.

Comment: The site URL that you are accessing through code, does it require authentication?

Comment: @Bharat, no I want to design it where it just runs without having to input auth each time. I'm trying to automate a process.

Comment: @Ozzah, can you please point me to some reference that could help me with that?

Comment: What is your endgame? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @mjwills, I want to automate downloading website, checking for a status on the page, and emailing that status. Then I'll setup a scheduled task to run my console app.

Comment: I would recommend to look for possibility of APIs if there are any to get the information that you are looking for. Otherwise it's more of an UI automation, that would be too much tightly coupled with how website is designed today

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1

Comment: I'm with @mjwills on this one, use an API rather than screenscrap. Are you trying to fix a symptom of the problem, the Build Agents get turned off rather than diagnosing the root cause why they're shutting down in the first place? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55071282/how-to-determine-why-an-agent-pool-is-offline-in-azure-dev-ops

Comment: The build agent is interactive and when server restarts it doesn’t automatically restart the agent. I know there’s an option to restart the agent after a restart but it’s not working for some unknown reason (guessing permission thing), hence this post.

Comment: And you can't determine that through the API?

Comment: I was just hoping for something quick and dirty.

Comment: "Logging in to a website with `WebClient`" is going to be dirty, but not quick. ;)